# Can I turn on grid for all plots with one line of code in R?

Tags: r, plot

can I turn on grid for all plots in r, instead of use `grid()` after each plot? such as

```
plot(1:10)
grid()
plot(2:20)
grid()
plot(3:30)
grid()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a wrapper function:

```
myplot <- function(x, ...) {
  plot(x, panel.first = grid(), ...)
}
```

Then use it as:

```
xx <- list(a = 1:10, b = 2:20, c = 3:30)
layout(matrix(1:3, ncol = 3))
for (i in seq_along(xx)) {
  myplot(xx[[i]])
}
layout(1)
```

which gives:

[image]

Note that I use the `panel.first` argument to `?plot.default` so as to put the grid *behind* the data when your way would put the grid in front. If you want to maintain that behaviour change `panel.first` to `panel.last`.

Comment: Thanks. In additional to wrapper function do we have something like  `par(grid=T)` or opinions(grid=T)?

Comment: no - see `ggplot()` in the **ggplot2** package for themeable graphics.